# How to config @EnableConfigurationProperties, @ConfigurationProperties with WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I want to read application.properties using

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties and @ConfigurationProperties.
```

I am able to do that with the following codes:

```
Application.java

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


ApplicationConfiguration.java

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private String port;

    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}

TestController.java

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        if (applicationConfiguration != null) {
            return applicationConfiguration.getPort();
        }
        return "1";
    }
}

application.properties

server.port = 8085
```

Now I want to replace `SpringBoot(Application.java)` with `WebApplicationInitializer` so that I can use an external container. Here is my code:

```
CommonInitializer.java

public class CommonInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationConfigWebApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.register(WebConfiguration.class);
        annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(annotationConfigWebApplicationContext));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
} 

WebConfiguration.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hello")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

After doing this, I am not able to get the port(port is null, applicationConfiguration is not null) in `application.proerties`. Any idea? What am I missing?

Comment: To deploy to an external container simply extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer` as explained in the reference guide.

Comment: why you use WebApplicationInitializer? you're building project spring

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. I am missing property file location!!

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", locations = "classpath:application.properties")
```

Seems spring boot does that for you automatically.

Comment: locations is  deprecated https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6220

Comment: locations is removed in Spring 2.0.0

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045955/using-configurationproperties-to-fill-map-in-generic-way) is much better and worked for me.