# Using ConfigurationProperties to fill Map in generic way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering, if there is a generic way to fill a map with properties you just know the prefix.

Assuming there are a bunch of properties like

```
namespace.prop1=value1
namespace.prop2=value2
namespace.iDontKnowThisNameAtCompileTime=anothervalue
```

I'd like to have a generic way to fill this property inside a map, something like

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("namespace")
public class MyGenericProps {
    private Map<String, String> propmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // setter and getter for propmap omitted

    public Set<String> returnAllKeys() {
        return propmap.keySet();
    }
}
```

Or is there another convenient way to collect all properties with a certain prefix, instead of iterating over all PropertySources in the environment?

Thanks
Hansjoerg

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As long as you're happy having every property added into the map, rather than just those that you don't know in advance, you can do this with `@ConfigurationProperties`. If you want to grab everything that's beneath `namespace` then you need to use an empty prefix and provide a getter for a map named `namespace`:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("")
public class CustomProperties {

    private final Map<String, String> namespace = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getNamespace() {
        return namespace;
    }

}
```

Spring Boot uses the `getNamespace` method to retrieve the map so that it can add the properties to it. With these properties:

```
namespace.a=alpha
namespace.b=bravo
namespace.c=charlie
```

The `namespace` map will contain three entries:

```
{a=alpha, b=bravo, c=charlie}
```

If the properties were nested more deeply, for example:

```
namespace.foo.bar.a=alpha
namespace.foo.bar.b=bravo
namespace.foo.bar.c=charlie
```

Then you'd use `namespace.foo` as the prefix and rename `namespace` and `getNamespace` on `CustomProperties` to `bar` and `getBar` respectively.

Note that you should apply `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to your configuration to enable support for `@ConfigurationProperties`. You can then reference any beans that you want to be processed using that annotation, rather than providing an `@Bean` method for them, or using `@Component` to have them discovered by component scanning:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)
public class YourApplication {
    // …
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on why we shouldn't annotate @ConfigurationProperties with @Component? It's done in the boot docs. Are you saying the preference is to use @EnableConfiguratinoProperties?

Comment: I was rushing and should have explained myself a bit better. What I wrote was worded too strongly. You should use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to switch on the support for `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated beans. At that point, you can reference your `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class to shortcut things and avoid having to declaring it as a bean. This is what Boot itself does in its own code. I'll reword that bit of my answer.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works for nested properties. `metrics.tagsAsSuffix.jvm.memory=area,id` with a prefix `metrics.tagsAsSuffix` doesn't get read into `Map<String, List<String>>` as `jvm.memory=[area,id]` but becomes `jvm=[]`

Comment: snakeyaml internally uses LinkedHashMap (it could be more appropriate for namespace)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that the getter method name mattered, I figured just the member variables name mattered. But it makes sense as it's getting an instance of the Map object and then adding to it.

Comment: Also you need to add `spring-boot-configuration-processor` in your `pom.xml` according with https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor

Answer (score 36):

In addition to this, my problem was that I didn't had multiple simple key/value properties but whole objects:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    query1:
      path: /api/apps/test1/query/**
      stripPrefix: false
      url: "https://test.url.com/query1"
    query2:
       path: /api/apps/test2/query/**
       stripPrefix: false
       url: "https://test.url.com/query2"
    index1:
       path: /api/apps/*/index/**
       stripPrefix: false
       url: "https://test.url.com/index"
```

Following Jake's advice I tried to use a Map with a Pojo like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
public class RouteConfig {
    private Map<String, Route> routes = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Route> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public static class Route {
        private String path;
        private boolean stripPrefix;
        String url;

        // [getters + setters]
    }
}
```

Works like a charm,
Thanks!

Comment: Note: it is absolutely crucial to have getters and setters for the fields you want filled from the properties. Even if the fields are public, Spring will not fill them if they don't have setters (or a getter, in the case of a map, I suppose).
One thing that I still don't understand is how Spring is able to deduce what class the map values should have (in this case: `Route`), since I always understood that generic type information is not available at runtime, but somehow it works. Magic, I guess.

Comment: @rem - some generics information is available at runtime for the declaration of classes, fields and methods information (method arguments and return value). see example http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html

Comment: Important! If you don't have getter for Map (getRoutes in this case), the values won't be set.

Answer (score 10):

I was going nuts trying to understand why @Andy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051377/2016436) wasn't working for me (as in, the `Map` was remaining empty) just to realize that I had Lombok's `@Builder` annotation getting in the way, which added a non-empty constructor. I'm adding this answer to emphasize that in order for `@ConfigurationProperties` to work on `Map`, the value type must have a No-Arguments constructor. This is also mentioned in Spring's [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding):

> Such arrangement relies on a default empty constructor and getters and setters are usually mandatory ...

I hope this will save someone else some time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a `MapFilter` class to handle this efficiently. Essentially, you create a `Map` and then filter it by specifying a prefix for the key. There is also a constructor that takes a `Properties` for convenience.

Be aware that this just filters the main map. Any changes applied to the filtered map are also applied to the base map, including deletions etc but obviously changes to the main map will not be reflected in the filtered map until something causes a rebuild.

It is also very easy (and efficient) to filter already filtered maps.

```
public class MapFilter<T> implements Map<String, T> {

    // The enclosed map -- could also be a MapFilter.
    final private Map<String, T> map;
    // Use a TreeMap for predictable iteration order.
    // Store Map.Entry to reflect changes down into the underlying map.
    // The Key is the shortened string. The entry.key is the full string.
    final private Map<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entries = new TreeMap<>();
    // The prefix they are looking for in this map.
    final private String prefix;

    public MapFilter(Map<String, T> map, String prefix) {
        // Store my backing map.
        this.map = map;
        // Record my prefix.
        this.prefix = prefix;
        // Build my entries.
        rebuildEntries();
    }

    public MapFilter(Map<String, T> map) {
        this(map, "");
    }

    private synchronized void rebuildEntries() {
        // Start empty.
        entries.clear();
        // Build my entry set.
        for (Map.Entry<String, T> e : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey();
            // Retain each one that starts with the specified prefix.
            if (key.startsWith(prefix)) {
                // Key it on the remainder.
                String k = key.substring(prefix.length());
                // Entries k always contains the LAST occurrence if there are multiples.
                entries.put(k, e);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MapFilter (" + prefix + ") of " + map + " containing " + entrySet();
    }

    // Constructor from a properties file.
    public MapFilter(Properties p, String prefix) {
        // Properties extends HashTable<Object,Object> so it implements Map.
        // I need Map<String,T> so I wrap it in a HashMap for simplicity.
        // Java-8 breaks if we use diamond inference.
        this(new HashMap<String, T>((Map) p), prefix);
    }

    // Helper to fast filter the map.
    public MapFilter<T> filter(String prefix) {
        // Wrap me in a new filter.
        return new MapFilter<>(this, prefix);
    }

    // Count my entries.
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    // Are we empty.
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return entries.isEmpty();
    }

    // Is this key in me?
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return entries.containsKey(key);
    }

    // Is this value in me.
    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        // Walk the values.
        for (Map.Entry<String, T> e : entries.values()) {
            if (value.equals(e.getValue())) {
                // Its there!
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Get the referenced value - if present.
    @Override
    public T get(Object key) {
        return get(key, null);
    }

    // Get the referenced value - if present.
    public T get(Object key, T dflt) {
        Map.Entry<String, T> e = entries.get((String) key);
        return e != null ? e.getValue() : dflt;
    }

    // Add to the underlying map.
    @Override
    public T put(String key, T value) {
        T old = null;
        // Do I have an entry for it already?
        Map.Entry<String, T> entry = entries.get(key);
        // Was it already there?
        if (entry != null) {
            // Yes. Just update it.
            old = entry.setValue(value);
        } else {
            // Add it to the map.
            map.put(prefix + key, value);
            // Rebuild.
            rebuildEntries();
        }
        return old;
    }

    // Get rid of that one.
    @Override
    public T remove(Object key) {
        // Do I have an entry for it?
        Map.Entry<String, T> entry = entries.get((String) key);
        if (entry != null) {
            entries.remove(key);
            // Change the underlying map.
            return map.remove(prefix + key);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Add all of them.
    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends T> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends T> e : m.entrySet()) {
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    // Clear everything out.
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // Just remove mine.
        // This does not clear the underlying map - perhaps it should remove the filtered entries.
        for (String key : entries.keySet()) {
            map.remove(prefix + key);
        }
        entries.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return entries.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> values() {
        // Roll them all out into a new ArrayList.
        List<T> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, T> v : entries.values()) {
            values.add(v.getValue());
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> entrySet() {
        // Roll them all out into a new TreeSet.
        Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> entrySet = new TreeSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> v : entries.entrySet()) {
            entrySet.add(new Entry<>(v));
        }
        return entrySet;
    }

    /**
     * An entry.
     *
     * @param <T>
     *
     * The type of the value.
     */
    private static class Entry<T> implements Map.Entry<String, T>, Comparable<Entry<T>> {

        // Note that entry in the entry is an entry in the underlying map.
        private final Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entry;

        Entry(Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<String, T>> entry) {
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKey() {
            return entry.getKey();
        }

        @Override
        public T getValue() {
            // Remember that the value is the entry in the underlying map.
            return entry.getValue().getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public T setValue(T newValue) {
            // Remember that the value is the entry in the underlying map.
            return entry.getValue().setValue(newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Entry)) {
                return false;
            }
            Entry e = (Entry) o;
            return getKey().equals(e.getKey()) && getValue().equals(e.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return getKey().hashCode() ^ getValue().hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry<T> o) {
            return getKey().compareTo(o.getKey());
        }
    }

    // Simple tests.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] samples = {
            "Some.For.Me",
            "Some.For.You",
            "Some.More",
            "Yet.More"};
        Map map = new HashMap();
        for (String s : samples) {
            map.put(s, s);
        }
        Map all = new MapFilter(map);
        Map some = new MapFilter(map, "Some.");
        Map someFor = new MapFilter(some, "For.");
        System.out.println("All: " + all);
        System.out.println("Some: " + some);
        System.out.println("Some.For: " + someFor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the places I pass through are not fully descriptive or are a bit outdated, so here are the full steps that I have taken to do that. Note: The Spring boot version I used is ***2.4.0***:

1. Add in pom.xml - spring-boot-configuration-processor

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
       <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a properties file and set data in it - *shared-messages.properties* Note: *"LIBRARY_10001"* is the map key, *"Unable to find the book"* is the map value

   ```
   shared-messages.messages.LIBRARY_10001=Unable to find the book
   shared-messages.messages.LIBRARY_10002=Book already exists
   ```
3. Create a Properties class that uses the properties file

   ```
   @ConfigurationProperties("shared-messages")
   @Getter
   public class LibraryProperties {
      private final Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<>();
   }
   ```
4. On the Application level, define the Property source and Enable Configuration Property

   ```
   @EnableConfigurationProperties(LibraryProperties.class)
   @PropertySource("shared-messages.properties")
   public class LibraryApplication {
     ....
   }
   ```
5. On the Service level, inject *"LibraryProperties"* class and access the property you need from

   ```
   @Autowired
   private LibraryProperties libraryProperties;


   libraryProperties.getMessages().get("LIBRARY_10001")
   ```

It might not be the perfect solution but I shared the way I managed to do that because I tried different combinations that didn't work for me