# How to represent Map in application.properties - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, application.properties

I have this old-fashion bean defined in xml:

```
<bean id="configReport" class="com.foo.config.ConfigReport">
    <property name="templates">
        <map>
            <entry key="1">
                <list>
                    <bean p:template="opt1" p:name="OPT1"
                        class="com.foo.config.ConfigReportTemplate" />
                </list>
            </entry>
            <entry key="-2">
                <list>
                    <bean p:template="opt-2" p:templateExtension="xlsx" p:name="OPT-2"
                        class="com.foo.config.ConfigReportTemplate" />
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTemplate">
        <bean p:template="empty" p:name="Empty"
            class="com.foo.config.ConfigReportTemplate" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to replace this bean to work with `application.properties` (config) via annotations like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045955/using-configurationproperties-to-fill-map-in-generic-way). It's ok with plain objects, but for me it's quiet hard to present this `<map>` entries in `application.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration a `Map` of properties in a simple `application.properties` format looks like a mess, I can suggest you consider a using of JSON format for these properties. It provides a more readable view, something like this:

```
{
  "reportTemplates": {
    1: {
      "template": "com.foo.config.FirstTemplate",
      "name": "OPT1"
    },
    2: {
      "template": "com.foo.config.SecondTemplate",
      "name": "OPT2"
    },

    "KEY" : {
      "field":"value"
    },

    ...
  }
}
```

And now you can use this config file in a java configuration to build necessary templates.

You can read how to work with JSON properties in Spring here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-json-properties