# Autowired bean in constructor not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to generate a set of beans in a `@Configuration` class with the `@PostConstruct` and `BeanFactoryAware`.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeansConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

     @Setter
     private BeanFactory beanFactory;

     @PostConstruct
     public void beanGenerator(){
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
        configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("a", new AClass())
    }

    @Bean
    public BClass b() {
        return new BClass();
    }
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {

 private final AClass a;
 private final BClass b;

 @Autowired
 public MyServiceImpl(AClass a, BClass b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
 }

}
```

When I try to start the application, the `AClass` bean cannot be loaded and I get this error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.acme......MyServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.acme....BClass' that could not be found.
```

The funny thing is that when I try to inject my beans changing the order, the application star successfully without any problems.

```
 @Autowired
 public MyServiceImpl(BClass b, AClass a){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
 }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: why are you doing this ? why not let spring create beans for you?

Comment: What is the purpose of registering beans manually? I don't know your needs, but marking them with `@Component` seems to make much more sense in this situation.

Comment: I have to create dynamically from the properties, a merge from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28374147) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651866)