# Using configurationProperties to fill a map of all properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

I was following the instructions for such case as er question and answers in this post.
[Using ConfigurationProperties to fill Map in generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045955/using-configurationproperties-to-fill-map-in-generic-way)

No Dice. The goal of me was to fill a map of countrycodes and names from a separate properties file.

**countrycodes.properties**

```
IM=Man
JE=Jersey
```

When I wired the following bean to a service and called the methods. Then the map was always returned as emtpty. For curiosity I created two field for IM and JE keys and those map finely.

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:countrycodes.properties")
public class CountryProperties {

    private Map<String, String> namespace = new HashMap<>();

    private String IM;
    private String JE;

//getters and setters
```

**random service.**

```
//empty map
var map = countryProperties.getNamespace();
//"jersey"
var jersey = countryProperties.getJE();
//"man"
var man = countryProperties.getIM();
```

The bean generated was exactly as posted in answer I linked but its behaviour did not correspond to the one described. There is no problem with property source location or soemthing like that as the other properties when added to bean map finely. Any ideas how i could get it to work